# Facebook login for business - it looks like this app isn't available to fix this, please contact

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, facebook-graph-api

1. Why does my Facebook business app, built with PHP Laravel and React for the front-end, display an error stating 'Your app is not available' despite being live?
2. I've created the app as a business type in the Facebook App
   Developer platform, utilizing permissions such as `public_profile`,
   `email`, `business_management`, and `catalog_management`. Although I
   obtained advanced access for `public_profile` and `email`, I'm
   struggling to acquire the same for `business_management` and
   `catalog_management`. Despite multiple review submissions (eight or
   nine times), the app consistently faces rejection in the Facebook
   App review process. My business is verified as a Tech Provider. How
   can I successfully obtain advanced access for `business_management`
   and `catalog_management` permissions to resolve this issue?

//route

```
Route::get('auth/facebook/callback',[FacebookLoginController::class,'handleFacebookCallback']);
Route::get('login/facebook',[FacebookLoginController::class,'redirectToFacebook']);
```

//controller

```
    public function redirectToFacebook()
{
    return Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()
        ->scopes(['email', 'catalog_management', 'business_management'])
        ->redirect();
}

public function handleFacebookCallback()
{
    try {
        $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()->user();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        Log::error('Facebook login error: ' . $e->getMessage());
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Facebook login error'], 500);
    }

    $fbData = FbUser::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->first();

    if ($fbData) {
        $fbData->update([
            'fb_id' => $user->id,
            'avatar' => $user->avatar,
            'name' => $user->name,
            'user_name' => $user->nickname,
            'email' => $user->email,
            'phone' => $user->phone,
            'token' => $user->token,
        ]);
    } else {
        FbUser::create([
            'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
            'fb_id' => $user->id,
            'avatar' => $user->avatar,
            'name' => $user->name,
            'user_name' => $user->nickname,
            'email' => $user->email,
            'phone' => $user->phone,
            'token' => $user->token,
        ]);
    }

    return '<script>window.close()</script>';
}
```

// react js [ front-end ]

```
      const handleFacebookLogin = () => {
    window.open("https://infinitefacebookfeed.com/login/facebook?token=" + window.sessionToken, "_blank")

    const fbdataIntervel = setInterval(() => {
      axiosHttp.get('getFbData').then((res) => {
        if (res.data.status == true) {
          setToastContent('Connected successfully');
          setToastActive(true);
          facebookBusinessAccountData()
          clearInterval(fbdataIntervel);
          setFbData(res.data.userData);
          setFbStatus(res.data.status);
        }
      }
      ).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
      )
    }
      , 1000);
  };
```

// env

```
FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID=11111111......example
FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET=000000......example
FACEBOOK_REDIRECT=https://infinitefacebookfeed.com/auth/facebook/callback
```

Login Error

[image]

- [Brief understanding watch screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uXusCh4OJBw&ab_channel=DigitalFatimah)
- [Brief understanding read the doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-omv1s_0FllT_GzPLwrkcHuZcdmnYrqIWR0zCTRhCPQ/edit?usp=sharing)
- [App link](https://apps.shopify.com/infinite-facebook-catalog-feed)

Comment: Were you ever able to figure out how to get this working? I'm having a very similar issue.

Comment: My issue is solved when I get advanced access to business_management and catalog_management.